# Application Insights REST API: Invalid application Id

Tags: azure

I am getting invalid application id, even though the App Id is correct. Testing here https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/metrics?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&metricId=requests%2Fcount&timespan=P1D

The app id is registered on the Microsoft.onmicrosoft.com tenant. I replace the appId (my app) and apiKey (App Insights Api Key) with my own

Comment: This looks more like a question for Microsoft support than for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little late, however I had the same issue today.

The problem is you're using the wrong Application ID. You need the Application ID from the API Access page (see below).

The ID is not your Application Insights resource name.

[image]